# No debugging symbols are available for the OS version installed on Apple Watch

Tags: xcode, watchkit, apple-watch, provisioning-profile, debug-symbols

You may get a message in Xcode that states:

> No debugging symbols are available for the OS version installed on [Apple Watch Name]. Verify that your internet connection is functional, then disconnect and reconnect the companion device to retry downloading symbols.

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot of issue]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After disconnecting the phone, watch, rebooting, nothing worked.

Ultimately, it appears that this is a bug appears to be caused by a failed installation of the WatchKit debugging package.

Steps install the package manually:

1. Disconnect iPhone from Mac
2. Launch `Xcode` from the terminal

> cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/
>
> ./Xcode -DVTDownloadableLogLevel 3

3. Press `CMD+F` and search for the output "Starting a download for Watch"
4. Quit `Xcode`
5. Open `Xcode` with flag to keep the downloaded files

> ./Xcode -DVTDownloadableLeaveTemporaryFiles 1

6. Quit `Xcode`
7. Mount the `Disk Image` then open the Package in `Pacifist` (https://www.charlessoft.com)
8. Open the following location

> ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/watchOS DeviceSupport/

9. Drag the `System` and `usr` folders from Pacifist into the folder
10. Reopen `Xcode`
11. Reconnect the iPhone to the Mac, and note that Apple Watch is connected successfully.

Adapted From Guide: http://indiestack.com/2016/12/installing-symbols-for-watchos/