# How to fix Xcode error: Could not locate device support files on iPhone with Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios11, iphone-x

**I have this error for the new iPhone X:**
[image: Error: Could not locate device support files]

> **Could not locate device support files.**
>
> *This iPhone X (Model A1865, A1901, A1902, A1903) is running iOS 11.1 (15B93), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode.*

I'm running the latest version of Xcode (Beta 9.2 9C32c) which doesn't support the iPhone X (iOS 11.1). The problem is it's a brand new iPhone, and there are no **older** Configuration Files to do the switch talked in most of the solved posts.

**Are there any other solution to this issue since downloading the latest version of Xcode is already what I'm running, and finding the Configuration Files to do the switch seems unlikely right now? Does anyone have those Configuration Files or know how to edit them to trick Xcode?**

Comment: Update xcode to latest version

Comment: Please read the question entirely before commenting, it's already the latest version.

Comment: i think this link may help you to download missed configuration files https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42261787/no-debugging-symbols-are-available-for-the-os-version-installed-on-apple-watch/42261788, thought this question is for apple-watch, this one actually downloads files that are missed to install during xcode installation, hope it helps

Comment: I had the same issue with my iPhone 8, Xcode Beta 9.2 did not support my version of iOS 11.1. However Xcode 9.1 does support my version of iOS 11.1. Have you tried Xcode 9.1 ?

Comment: @Bhargavi I tried the referenced post but it didn't work.

Comment: @ChrisHerbst I will download Xcode 9.1 and report back when it's done

Comment: @ChrisHerbst Wow, your answer worked. Can't believe the latest version doesn't (I always have at least 2 versions installed and it's getting kind of ridiculous at this point). Feel free to post your comment as an answer and I'll gladly accept it. Thanks again!

Comment: @user2888798 Pleasure. Have posted answer

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had the same issue with my iPhone 8, Xcode Beta 9.2 did not support my version of iOS 11.1.

However Xcode 9.1 does support my version of iOS 11.1

Comment: Can you send me that device support file (Signature) for ios 11.1

Comment: @Mind_Sparkles can you please indicate how I can generate that files for you?

Comment: If you have installed xcode 9.1 then you can go to the path - zip that folder and upload in some drive and share link here.
Path is - /Applications/Xcode 9.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/11.1

Comment: I want folder 11.1 , If you can share please share it, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please generate that file for me?

Comment: @Mind_Sparkles sorry for the wait, I have compressed and busy uploading to gdrive now (internet not very fast). Will post link once done

Comment: @Mind_Sparkles here you go: https://drive.google.com/file/d/13aiB1FrxwKO4n4bGl67-Ols8q9htFjic/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hey @Chris Herbst Can you please keep uploading all latest simulators here? just update the links with you answer here.

Comment: 11.2 files please.

Answer (score 88):

## Answer: Xcode: Could not locate device support files

Well, I found non of the answers logged out here aren't complete and sustainable. So here we go.

### Most importantly don't waste your time and internet bandwidth downloading Xcode just to resolve this issue which you can do within few MBs and little bit of OS know-how!!!

**Step 1:**
Following GitHub Repository seems to be up to date with all the required **`Support Files`** which are helpful to resolve. And it seems like this repository gets updated quicker as possible. Check out it for yourself and you are halfway done.

> https://github.com/filsv/iPhoneOSDeviceSupport

**Step 2:**
Select and download the Support files which are missing for your Xcode, which you can get the clue out of the above alert message. In my case I was informed to download **11.4 (15FCA...something)**. So I went and downloaded the latest iOS Support files:

Which were under the path of iPhoneOSDeviceSupport/11.4 (15F5061c)/

```
DeveloperDiskImage.dmg
DeveloperDiskImage.dmg.signature
```

[image: Files within the Repository for 11.4 latest version]

**Step 3:**
And then place them inside the DeviceSupport folder which is in a related path to your Xcode installation. In my case, I've installed Xcode 9.2 so my path to DeviceSupport looks like as follows:

```
/Applications/Xcode-9.2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport
```

**Step 4**
Place the two files you downloaded in a folder named `11.4 (15F5061c)`.
**Clue:** In your case make sure to name it after the specific iOS version you downloaded the files.

**Step 5:**
Quit Xcode app if you had been already using it previously. Re-open it and try to run your app on your iPhone (or in iDevice of your previous attempt). Xcode will first warn you saying something like following:

> Preparing debugger support for Randika's iPhone 6s

[image: Preparing debugger support for Randika's iPhone 6s in Xcode]

Soon after it's completed (probably after several attempts that you may have to try reconnecting your iPhone to Xcode), you would be able to successfully run your app on your preferred device.

**How could you find this path?**
Go to your Applications folder, locate Xcode-x.x.app file, right click on the Xcode app and select "Show package contents" as follows:

[image: Where to find the DeviceSupport]

And then navigate to the *DeviceSupport* folder within the *Finder App* as follows:

[image: Navigate the folder tree]

Hope this would be helpful to any of you!

Cheers!

Comment: 10 thumbs up! Updating Xcode didn't work for my iPod Touch 6th gen w/iOS 11.4, but this method did.

Comment: Great Answer, support's files for ios 12 in xcode 8.2.1 also

Comment: Yes, it still works! I'm happy I have documented this which is helpful for me also.
Tested for Xcode Version 10.0 (10A255) and added support for iOS 12.1 ---> Works

Comment: My greatest respect! It still works and you have documented it in an easily understandable way.

Comment: Thanks! I just used this to add iOS 13.4 support to Xcode 11.2. (I would otherwise have had to upgrade to Catalina to use the latest Xcode. Putting that off as long as possible.)

Answer (score 16):

This error can be fixed with 2 ways.

1.You need to keep updated with latest Xcode versions.

2.You can fix it without updating to latest Xcode, in this you just need to update device support file,

To update device support file just follow the steps,

You can find the Device support file and update it with the below path details,

Path-

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceS‌​upport/
```

You can download device support file from this links

- [11.1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13aiB1FrxwKO4n4bGl67-Ols8q9htFjic/view)
- [11.2](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1MzbaLZYAHZOHqJk5i1wWJKt7n9jj0hrQ)
- [All iPhoneOSDeviceSupport](https://github.com/filsv/iPhoneOSDeviceSupport)

Comment: how do you even go to that path? It's giving me 'No such file or directory' in console.

Comment: ok let me update path, you can try this one - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceS‌​upport/

Answer (score 10):

You can download all **iOS-DeviceSupport**

***iOS 13.0***

- [13.3 (17C54)](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/blob/master/DeviceSupport/13.3%20(17C54).zip)
- [13.2 (11C29) (From Xcode11.3)](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/blob/master/DeviceSupport/13.2(FromXcode11.3(11C29)).zip)
- [13.2 (11B500) (From xCode11.2.1)](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/raw/master/DeviceSupport/13.2(FromXcode11.2.1(11B500)).zip)
- [13.2 (From xCode_11.2.1_GM_Seed)](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/raw/master/DeviceSupport/13.2%20(FromXcode_11.2.1_GM_Seed).zip)
- [13.2 (From xCode_11.2_Beta_1)](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/raw/master/DeviceSupport/13.2.zip)
- [13.1 (From xCode_13.1)](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/raw/master/DeviceSupport/13.1.zip)
- [13.0 (From xCode_11_Beta_7)](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/raw/master/DeviceSupport/13.0%20(FromXcode_11_Beta_7_xip).zip)
- [13.0 (From xCode_11_Beta)](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/raw/master/DeviceSupport/13.0.zip)

***iOS 12.3***

- [12.3 (From xCode 11 beta)](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/raw/master/DeviceSupport/12.3.zip)

***iOS 12.2***

- [12.2 (16E226). (From Xcode_10.2.1)](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/raw/master/DeviceSupport/12.2%20(16E226).zip)
- [12.2 (16E5212e). (From Xcode_10.2)](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/raw/master/DeviceSupport/12.2%20(16E5212e).zip)
- [12.2 (16E5181e). (From Xcode_10.2_Beta)](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/raw/master/DeviceSupport/12.2%20(16E5181e).zip)

***iOS 12.1***

- [12.1             (From Xcode_10.1)](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/raw/master/DeviceSupport/12.1.zip)
- [12.1 (16B91).    (From Xcode_10.1)](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/raw/master/DeviceSupport/12.1%20(16B91).zip)
- [12.1 (16B5084a). (From Xcode_10.1_Beta_3)](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/raw/master/DeviceSupport/12.1%20(16B5084a).zip)
- [12.1 (16B5068g). (From Xcode_10.1_Beta_2)](https://github.com/AshvinGudaliya/iOS-DeviceSupport/raw/master/DeviceSupport/12.1%20(16B5068g).zip)
- [12.1 (16B5059d). (From Xcode_10.1_Beta)](https://github.com/AshvinGudaliya/iOS-DeviceSupport/raw/master/DeviceSupport/12.1%20(16B5059d).zip)

**How to add a file in xCode**

- Open Finder
- Open the application folder
- Find the Xcode app inside
- Click on Xcode, right click -> show package contents
- Find the supported real machine test files in the following directory hierarchy:

  Contents -> Developer -> Platforms -> iPhoneOS.platform -> DeviceSupport(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport)

The above directory is the real version of iOS that Xcode supports real machine debugging, as shown below:
Then copy the latest DeviceSupport file to this directory through other channels **and restart XCode** to debug with the latest iOS device.

[image]

Comment: I did this and it worked, thank you. But my question is, why should we even need to do this? I've been developing with Xcode for nearly ten years, and I have never had to do this before now. What has changed?

Answer (score 1):

I'm uncomfortable downloading shards from 3rd parties; also, it sounds like the iOS 13.2 support file linked above is based on a beta, which now crashes.

I would recommend downloading Xcode directly from Apple, and install the new version side-by-side with the version of Xcode which you need to use (if you're pinned by a Swift binary framework, for example).

1. rename your current Xcode application bundle (Xcode --> Xcode_11)
2. download latest Xcode from AppStore (Xcode 11.2)
3. launch new Xcode, installing Command Line Tools, then exit
4. launch your older Xcode (Xcode_11), and build and run on device

Answer (score 0):

In my case, device support files were already present but I was still facing the issue. The reason was that folder present at this path

`/Applications/Xcode-9.2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport`
 was having name **12.1 (16B91)** but the xcode was giving error for **12.1 (16C101)** so renaming the folder to **12.1 (16C101)** did the trick

Answer (score -1):

I was able to run it, by first using BuddyBuild.com to send me a tester app through email, that I downloaded successfully.  After that, I was able to build the app.

Answer (score -1):

- Open Xcode show package content
- go to /Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport and drop the 13.0 folder into this folder and restart the Xcode.

Download the file here:
https://bitbucket.org/bneves/ios13_devicesupport_xcode_10.3/

Comment: This is for the ios13 version.