# Could not locate device support files with Xcode 9.0 and iOS 11.1

Tags: ios, xcode

I currently have Xcode 9.0 and I just updated my phone and I'm getting this:

[image]

How can I fix this without updating Xcode (I don't have enough bandwidth)?

Comment: You need Xcode 9.1 for iOS 11.1 and Xcode 9.2 for iOS 11.2. If you can't update Xcode you shouldn't have updated the OS on your development iOS device.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47119186/how-to-fix-xcode-error-could-not-locate-device-support-files-on-iphone-x-11-1